# How to fetch the latest entry in a table in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way we can retrieve the last modified or appended rows only in a Postgres table?

Is there any control/management table in Postgres that stores the updates in table and from where we can fetch values/rows that were last updated/added?

Lets say we have a table like this -

```
col1.  col2 
 a       1
 b       2
```

Then I update the table -

```
update tablename set col2 = 3 where col1 = a;
```

So now the table looks like -

```
col1.  col2 
 a       3
 b       2
```

What I need is a way I can get the records or entire rows in any table those were updated/added recently. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: You can add an `updated_at` column and an update trigger. See [Automatic timestamps with PostgreSQL](https://x-team.com/blog/automatic-timestamps-with-postgresql/) might be useful.

Comment: what you need is an audit functionality that can be achieved using either triggers or enabling audit at the application level.